# Can not get munin to work

Tags: linux, debian, munin

Have installed munin on several servers, but in the recent months I can not install it anymore

```
apt-get install munin
```

version 2.0.49-1

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  munin.myserver.com;
    
    root  /var/cache/munin/www;
    
    location / {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location ^~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph)(.*);
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/munin/fcgi-graph.sock;
        include  fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

When I try to restart munin

```
# /etc/init.d/munin-node restart
-bash: /etc/init.d/munin-node: No such file or directory
```

This directory is created but is empty (only one sub-directory "static")

```
/var/cache/munin/www
```

Comment: You installed and configured the Munin collector, then tried to restart the Munin node, which apparently isn't even installed.

Comment: I just follow a set of command lines which I have always done?

Comment: but why is `/var/cache/munin/www` empty?

Comment: Works for me on Debian 10. Make sure that munin is installed correctly, post output of `dpkg -l | grep munin` and `ls -Al /etc/init.d/munin-node`

Comment: Also notice that `/etc/init.d/munin-node` is provided by a package called `munin-node`, however it *should* get installed by `apt-get install munin`.

Comment: `ls -l /etc/init.d/munin*` please

Comment: ok, now I got `munin-node` installed but `/var/cache/munin/www` is still empty with only the subdir `static`

Comment: Now content is written to `/var/cache/munin/www` :)

Comment: @clarkk: so does it work for you now?

Comment: Yes its working after installing `munin-node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`munin` and `munin-node` are two different packages, because they do something different. A Munin node is the host which is monitored by Munin. There can be any number of hosts running the Munin node service which are monitored by a single Munin server.

So, you want to have one central Munin server which collects and plots the data, and several Munin nodes these data get collected from. Usually, Munin node is also installed on the same host as Munin so that this system can collect data from itself.

In a single host setup, there are both packages installed and configured independently on the same host.

Also,  on Debian, use `service munin start` or `service munin-node start` respectively to start the services, as SysV may be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

/etc/init.d/munin-node is provided by `munin-node` package as shown by
`apt-file`:

```
root@e1d504d8b298:/# apt-file update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Contents (deb) [37.3 MB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Contents (deb) [44.2 kB]
Fetched 37.4 MB in 7s (5626 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
root@e1d504d8b298:/# apt-file search /etc/init.d/munin-node
munin-node: /etc/init.d/munin-node
```

Running `apt-get install munin` however should install it as it's the
recommended dependency:

```
root@03c170fe928a:/# apt-cache depends munin | grep munin-node
  Recommends: munin-node
```

It's possible that you ran `apt-get install munin` with
`--no-install-recommends` flag, have this flag set by default in apt
config file or removed munin-node inadvertently after it has been
installed.